# How can I get rid of brackets in a variable in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to tidy up a data frame.It includes a variable called "nutrition", which looks like this:

```r
nutrition
[51.5, 0.0, 13.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0]
[173.4, 18.0, 0.0, 17.0, 22.0, 35.0, 1.0]
[269.8, 22.0, 32.0, 48.0, 39.0, 27.0, 5.0]
```

Subsequently, all of the other data in the "nutrition" column have brackets at the beginning and end of them. I would like for these 3 cells, and for all the other cells in the nutrition column to look like this (with their respective data):

```r
nutrition
51.5, 0.0, 13.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0
173.4, 18.0, 0.0, 17.0, 22.0, 35.0, 1.0
269.8, 22.0, 32.0, 48.0, 39.0, 27.0, 5.0
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `gsub("(\\[|\\])","", nutrition)`

Comment: Error in gsub("[", "", recipes3) : 
  invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''

I get this message every time

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected the expression.

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
gsub("[","",gsub("]","",nutrition)
```

This has the least amount of regex possible because I hate that shit. But if code optimization/speed is an issue you should look into regex to capture "[" and "]" at the same time.

Otherwise

`gsub(pattern,replacement,variable)` simply takes the first argument of what you want to replace, the second as the replacement (in your case empty char) and the string from which to replace it.

In a flow this might look like:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(nutrition = gsub("[","",gsub("]","",nutrition)))
```

Thanks to @Martin Gal we also now know the regex:

"(\[|\])"

so

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(nutrition = gsub("(\\[|\\])","",,nutrition))
```

Comment: thank you both so much, i"ll try this out right now!

Comment: with more regex `gsub("\\[(.*)\\]", "\\1", nutrition)`. Explanation: `\\[` since `[ ]` has special meaning in regex we use double backslashes on each square bracket to let it know that we what the actual bracket character. `( )` regular brackets store whatever is found inside of them to later be recalled by `\\1`. finally we include any length `*` of any character `.` as part of the pattern.